# If Statement to check if a screen exists before sending form. c# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, screen

So I've written a countdown timer for my church using Visual Studio c# (first program I've written) I've created a controller (Form1) and the countdown timer (Form2) and I have already set it all up to automatically start the countdown timer on Form2, scale Form2 to maximum screen size along with the text in the form and I can send it between monitor 1, 2 or 3. no worries. the issue I've got is that i need an if statement that checks if screen 1,2,3 (0,1,2) exists before sending. At the moment my program crashes because it can't find screen.allscreens[2] (this is because i don't have a 3rd monitor attach, deliberately to test this code).

Please let me know if you require more information. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You answer to your own question. You can simply use:

```
if(Screen.AllScreens.Length>0)
{
//some of your code
}
```

Or using Linq:

```
if(Screen.AllScreens.Any())
{
//some of your code
}
```

Comment: Ha thanks! that did it! I Just adjusted the variable (0) to "1" to check for second screen and "2" to check for 3rd.